# MacBook Keychain problems

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud, keychain

Had a new MacBook at Christmas linked to iCloud password.

Forgot iCloud password so Apple reset it for me. I can login to MacBook using new iCloud password now but Keychain won't allow me to open Local Items keychain says password is incorrect I guess it wants old password that I forgot.

Please help?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Open KeyChain app
2. Lock the Keychain by clicking the lock on the top left corner, if it isn't already.
3. Unlock the Keychain using your Admin Password. Reset iCloud KeyChain (it may ask you to automatically - if so, say yes. If not. If not, do it manually).
4. Restart computer.

See if that works.  Or check this thread:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5467304?tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you can't unlock that without the old password that locked it.